# i want all my database names to be displayed in textbox,how can i do it?

Tags: php

Below is the code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id,Customer_Name FROM bewar';
$retval = mysqli_query( $con,$sql );

if(! $retval ) {
die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retval)) {
$cname=$row["Customer_Name"];
echo "<table>
<form>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>Slip No.</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input  type='text' name='date' id='date' 
 value=".date("Y/M/d").'  required></td>
        <td><input id="name" type="text" name="name" value= '.$cname.' 
 required></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>';
 }
 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Above code is showing only the last name in database but i want all names to be displayed in textboxes

Comment: Side note: `<form>` cannot be made child of `<table>`.

Comment: You don't even quote the HTML attribute.

Comment: Does "view source" for the page show more than one table?

Comment: Actually second name is not displaying in textbox but available in page source.

Comment: Take out the table headers out of while loop. And use only <td> tags inside while loop. Also you might be getting errors as you echo tags are not in sequence.

Comment: I did that but the issue which i m facing now is that,second name is taken as attribute.